# Rails 4 Monkey patch throws exception when executing class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, monkeypatching, sorcery

I have a rails project which uses [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) for authentication.  I want to modify the behavior of the password reset function such that it does not create a new reset token if one already exists.  I believe the relevant code is:

```
  def deliver_reset_password_instructions!
    config = sorcery_config
    # hammering protection
    return false if config.reset_password_time_between_emails.present? && self.send(config.reset_password_email_sent_at_attribute_name) && self.send(config.reset_password_email_sent_at_attribute_name) > config.reset_password_time_between_emails.seconds.ago.utc
    self.class.sorcery_adapter.transaction do
      generate_reset_password_token!
      send_reset_password_email! unless config.reset_password_mailer_disabled
    end
  end
```

I created the following monkey patch to rectify the problem:

```
Sorcery::Model::Submodules::ResetPassword::InstanceMethods.module_eval do
  def deliver_reset_password_instructions!
    config = sorcery_config
    # hammering protection
    return false if config.reset_password_time_between_emails.present? && self.send(config.reset_password_email_sent_at_attribute_name) && self.send(config.reset_password_email_sent_at_attribute_name) > config.reset_password_time_between_emails.seconds.ago.utc
    self.class.sorcery_adapter.transaction do
      generate_reset_password_token! unless reset_password_token.present?
      send_reset_password_email! unless config.reset_password_mailer_disabled
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error in development:

`` undefined method `sorcery_adapter' for #<Class:0x00000008b82d08> ``

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions concerning why this is happening, how to create a functional patch, or a better way of going about the whole thing.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you loading your monkey patch? `prepend` in an initializer has worked for me before.

Comment: I am loading it in an initializer.  The patch doesn't throw an exception if I don't include the line with ```self.class.sorcery_adapter```.  If I change that block to ```puts "test msg"``` it prints the message instead of creating the token.  The patch seems to be loading correctly.

Comment: What does `self.class.name` return within the block?

Comment: ```self.class.name``` returns ```Realtor```.  Realtor is the name of the model which is authenticated using Sorcery.

Comment: `sorcery_adapter` is injected as a class singleton method on `ActiveRecord::Base` as per https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/54c8b9ac6a71c36eb4f15e30355bcc38e69e9fc6/lib/sorcery.rb. No idea why it's missing at this point, try the instance version by removing the `.class` call?

Comment: Thanks, but removing ```.class``` results in the same error.